# Is there a way that i can add a tableview inside an alertview using sdcalertview?

Tags: swift, xcode

i would like to know if this is possible or an alternative? i just need multi-select in my alert view and Im struggling to find a good solution

Comment: https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog and https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentr are 2 good libraries that allow you to present a view controller as an alert. Then you can just customize it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I use a library called MSAlertController to do this, I am successfully embedding tables in my alerts using their `MSAlertControllerEmbedComponent` then passing a tableview in.

You can get it here: https://github.com/MilitiaSoftworks/MSAlertController

It's a pretty new library so unfortunately they don't have any cocoapods support and their docs are still a WIP, but I can help with your implementation if you need it. I found it to be quite straightforward though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SDCAlertView before, but you can present a normal ViewController, with your tableView, using `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` this will present your VC, but with the previousVC still in the background.

Visually it looks a lot like a alert, but you have complete control over what it looks like.

```
let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.main) as ViewController
vc.dataSource = datasourceWith(***.****ToDownload())
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```